# How to set less xAxis data with more column chart data in highcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Here is my ts file code

```
xAxis:{
categories:['row-1','row-2','row-3','row-4'],
max:3
},
plotOptions:{
column:{
stacking:'normal'
}
}
series:[
{
type:'column',
data:[12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90]
},{
type:'column',
data:[12,32,43,54,65,76,87,98,91]
}
]
```

Below is my working code i want to the xAxis as it is and i need all the data entered in the series. I am new to highcharts so please
I used max so that my xAxis wont extend and i tried every way i can but i can't get the result
[STACKBLITZ CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-bar-chart-hhmvc3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Below image is how i want my chart to be**

[image: this is how i want my chart to look like]

Comment: Hi, I'm unsure if I understood correctly, so could you please specify/provide an image of what would you like to achieve? Regards!

Comment: @magdalena I added the image as you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that is by adding empty strings to the categories.

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['', 'row-1', '', 'row-2', '', 'row-3', '', 'row-4', '']
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8uy9vo0t/

You can also use `labels.formatter` to add categories directly to the relevant positions on the axis.

```
  xAxis: {
    tickLength: 0,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        let position = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
          if (this.pos === position) {
            return categories[i]
          }
                    position = position + 2
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a1jv9nqL/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Another approach would be using **Grouped Categories** module.

```
  xAxis: {
    tickWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      style: {
        visibility: 'hidden',
        fontSize: '0px',
      },
      groupedOptions: [{
        style: {
          visibility: 'visible',
          fontSize: '12px',
        },
      }],
    },

    categories: [{
        name: "row-1",
        categories: ["0", "1"]
      }, {
        name: "row-2",
        categories: ["0", "1"]
      },
      {
        name: "row-3",
        categories: ["0", "1"]
      },
      {
        name: "row-4",
        categories: ["0", "1", "2"]
      }
    ]
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3nkeswL5/

**Documentation:**
https://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/

You can also consider using **Stacked and grouped columns** if your data structure can be modified.

**Official demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped

Comment: is this the only possible way ?.I wanna do it in a best practice way that's why i am asking this  is. Adding empty string to `xAxis`  is not good idea sorry for saying this but i need some best practice answer BTW thanks for the effort

Comment: Hi! Usually, there are several solutions for one issue, and it's hard to indicate which one is the best practice. Your example is not so obvious to implement and will require using a little workaround in every approach. I've edited my answer, where you can find two other approaches to choose from. Regards!